# Maven generating javadoc and deploying it into virtual machine

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, javadoc, maven-plugin

I need to generate javadocs by using maven for a project. There are three steps;
- checkout source from github repo
- creating javadocs for these sources
- deploying javadocs into our AWS server

I have done checking out sources from github repo and creating javadocs for these sources by using maven, but I am having hard time to deploy these generated javadocs into our AWS server in the same pom.xml which are shown below;

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.companyname</groupId>
    <artifactId>FOO-FOO</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>nic.yyy</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>ec2-user</id>
            <name>companyname-releases</name>
            <url>scp://${deploy-destination}/../../var/www/FOO</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ec2-user</id>
            <name>companyname-snapshots</name>
            <url>scp://${deploy-destination}/../../var/www/FOO</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <deploy-destination>serverid..</deploy-destination>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <deploy-destination>serverid..</deploy-destination>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <properties>
        <project.scm.id>git</project.scm.id>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <url>https://github.com/companyname/foo.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/companyname/foo.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:companyname/foo.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <email>name@mail.com</email>
            <name>Name Surname</name>
            <url>https://github.com/username</url>
            <id>username</id>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/site</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.less</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>downloads-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <description>Official ${project.name} build of the ${project.version} release</description>
                    <override>true</override>
                    <includeAttached>true</includeAttached>
                    <server>github</server>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
                <configuration>
                     <!--Make SURE you have ec2-user defined in settings.xml, with pointer to .pem file so scp can get to ec2 instance-->
                        <server>
                          <id>ec2-user</id>
                          <username>ec2-user</username>
                          <privateKey>/Users/username/Desktop/foobar.key</privateKey>
                        </server>
                    <serverId>ec2-user</serverId>
                    <fromDir>${basedir}/target/classes</fromDir>
                    <includes>**</includes>
                    <excludes>pom.xml</excludes>
                    <url>scp://${deploy-destination}/../../var/www/FOO</url>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <flowInitContext>
                        <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
                        <developBranchName>develop</developBranchName>
                        <featureBranchPrefix>feature/</featureBranchPrefix>
                        <releaseBranchPrefix>release/</releaseBranchPrefix>
                        <hotfixBranchPrefix>hotfix/</hotfixBranchPrefix>
                        <versionTagPrefix />
                    </flowInitContext>

                    <noDeploy>true</noDeploy>
                    <pullMaster>true</pullMaster>
                    <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                    <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
                    <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                    <alwaysUpdateOrigin>true</alwaysUpdateOrigin>
                    <noReleaseMerge>false</noReleaseMerge>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

These pom.xml successfully checks out(`mvn scm:checkout`) the sources and run javadocs(`mvn javadoc:javadoc`). Could you please help me about deploying javadocs into our AWS server by editing this pom.xml?